# typo3 read configuration options in typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I've tried several approaches to read the configuration options of my plugin in typoscript, but none of them seem to work

```
    ajax.30 = TEXT
    ajax.30.value =   {plugin.tx_parser.settings.numVar}
    ajax.40 < {tx_parser.settings.numVar}
    ajax.50 < {tx_parser.settings.numVar}
    ajax.80 = TEXT
    ajax.80.value = {options.numVar}
    ajax.90 = TEXT
    ajax.90.value = {settings.numVar}
```

Can anyone please explain me the syntax or post a link where it is explained; I can use ext_conf_template.txt explained here https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/ConfigurationOptions/Index.html but I didn't get these options in typoscript.

[image: typoscript object browser]

All I want is to access (in typoscript) the configuration options of the following picture

[image: the needed extension configuration options]

If I browse Constants I don't see any of these options

[image: the constants browser]

If I add my plugin to the site I see some plugin options but none of them I wanted

[image]

Comment: Configuration added to the Extension configuration *are not* the same thing as TypoScript constants. And if you add an Extension Configuration option it will not be added to TypoScript as a constant. --- All constants have to be defined in your template record either in the constants field, or by using static files and include them in your template record.

Answer (score 1):

You can use constants with this syntax in TypoScript setup or constants

```
var = {$plugin.tx_parser.settings.numVar}
```

So in your case:

```
ajax.30 = TEXT
ajax.30.value = {$plugin.tx_parser.settings.numVar}
```

See https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/UsingSetting/Constants.html

To assign an earlier declared setup value you would use the `<` (object copy) operator

```
ajax.30 = TEXT
ajax.30.value < plugin.tx_parser.settings.numVar
```

Here is an on overview of its syntax: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/TypoScriptSyntax/Syntax/TypoScriptSyntax.html

The difference between constants and setup is essential. You can check in the backend in the module `Template` -> Template browser - see https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/UsingSetting/Debugging.html

Comment: Unfortunately all I get out of 
        page.25 = TEXT
        page.25.value = {$plugin.tx_parser.settings.numVar}
is exactly the text passed to the value,ie. {$plugin.tx_parser.settings.numVar} in the frontend

Comment: That's weird. Can you show a screenshot of your PAGE object from "Template" › TypoScript Object Browser (select "Browse": "Setup")? Selecting "Display Constants": "Substituted constants in green" might help identify unsubstitued constants. You might check the Object Browser with "Browse": "Constants" to verify your constant is really there, too.

Comment: From your screenshots I learnt now that it is not about TypoScript constants but about Extension configuration. There is no possibility to access that directly in TypoScript. You would need to use a TypoScript userFunc - have a look here how to access that in PHP: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/ConfigurationOptions/Index.html#accessing-saved-options